# Rails FormHelper collection_check_boxes not working with Mongoid collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have two models:

```
class LocationPreferences
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :neighborhoods,
                          class_name: "Neighborhood",
                          inverse_of: nil
end

class Neighborhood
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name,         type: String, default: nil
end
```

I'm building a form using Rails [FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes), and want to create a list of checkboxes for each neighborhood this set of preferences could include. So, my form builder looks like:

```
= form_for preferences do |form|
  = form.collection_check_boxes :neighborhoods, Neighborhood.all, :name, :name
```

However, this throws the error:

```
undefined method `id' for "Downtown":String
```

It appears that it calls the `name` method of the first Neighborhood to get its value, which it should, but then for some odd reason tries to invoke `id` on the String it gets back from calling `name`... frankly, it makes no sense. What's going on here? And how can I fix it?

- David

**UPDATE**:

Get this... I tried using another FormHelper other than what came bundled with Rails, in this case [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations). Using the same `collection_check_boxes` produce the same error. However, using the following seemed to work just fine.

```
= form.association :neighborhoods, collection: Neighborhood.all, as: :check_boxes
```

This isn't really a 'fix' so I'm not going to mark it as the solution. I find it hard to believe that Rails' `collection_check_boxes` is broken out of the box in its simplest example, so I'd guess this has something to do with Mongoid not playing nice with this FormHelper. I'd still like to know how to get the original function working.